# How to access swagger endpoints securely?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, swagger, swagger-ui

I have added swagger ui in my application, earlier below two url's i was able to access directly without any authentication.

```
     http://localhost:1510/swagger-ui.html
     http://localhost:1510/v2/api-docs
```

i need secure swagger urls, don't want anybody directly see the api details of my application.

Note :- For authentication purpose i am using JWT with spring security in my application.

SO in order to secure swagger URLS , i have made entry in spring seurity config .. below code

```
       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/userLogin").permitAll()           
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)          
    .and()
        .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());

}
```

and when i am trying to access swagger urls , i am getting below exception on browser and as well as on eclipse console.

```
 org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

How can i pass the jwt token to see the swagger page ?

Comment: Any help on this question ?